# How can I access the rows in sections in my container?

Tags: ios, swift, containers, tableview

I created a side menu programmatically with two sections (4 + 2 rows).
My main controller is a `UIViewController`. In order to create a grouped table view with different sections within my view controller I had to place a container view inside of my of it and embedding in my other VC with the table view.

To access my rows in different sections I created an Enum first:

```
enum MenuType: Int, CaseIterable {

    case a, b, c, d
    case e, f

    var section: Int {
        switch self {
        case .a, .b, .c, .d : return 0
        case .e, .f: return 1
        }
    }

    var row: Int? {
        switch self.section {
        case 0: return self.rawValue
        case 1: return self.rawValue - MenuType.allCases.filter{ $0.section < self.section }.count
        default: return nil
        }
    }
}
```

To call the **MenuTypes** in my **MainVC**

```
var didTapMenuType: ((MenuType) -> Void)?
```

To select the correct section with the respective rows I tried the following:

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let menuType = MenuType.allCases.first(where: { $0.section == indexPath.section && $0.row == indexPath.row }) else {return}
        dismiss(animated: true) { [weak self] in
            self?.didTapMenuType?(menuType)
        }
    }
```

And in my **MainVC** I did a **Switch-Case** to apply actions to the different cases:

```
func transition(_ menuType: MenuType)
switch menuType {
        case .a:
            // action
        case .b:
         ...
```

And finally call it when the user taps on the side menu button:

```
//button action ...
 menuViewController.didTapMenuType = { menuType in
        self.transitionToNew(menuType)
```

Transition works great. But when selecting a row nothing happens.
It worked when my main controller was a **UITableViewController**. The only thing I changed was to embedding in my table view into the container of my **UIViewController** to gain more control of the layout (it was frustrating to layout views inside of a table view controller).

Can anyone tell me what I am missing? I guess the problem is that my **tableView(disSelectRowAt:)** function does not apply to the table view inside of my container!?

Sorry for the long question but I can not figure out a working solution.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: can u share a screenshot?

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/a/HyXMJzz) you go

Comment: tableview didselect is working or not?

Comment: It is not working

Comment: Then implement the below given delegate methods or come to chat.

Comment: As mentioned below: I can not assign the table view to the view controller. It is embedded in my container view. I can't set any delegates because I don't get a reference

Comment: You can... assign delegate in UIView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have not connected your `tableView` delegate to your `viewController` either in Interface Builder, or in code, in you `viewDidLoad` for instance:

```
myTableView.delegate = self
```

**EDIT**: Don't forget to make your view controller to conform to `UITableViewDelegate`

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate { ... }
```

Comment: How do I connect the table view delegate? I only have a segue from my container view to it. When I try to drag it anywhere it shows only the options for push and so on.+

Comment: In the view controller in which you implemented `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` add the line of the answer in your `viewDidLoad`. (of course use the name of your own table view) And don't forget to make your view controller conform to `UITableViewDelegate`. I edited my answer.

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/a/HyXMJzz) is my table view shown. Do you mean to create a delegate programmatically? I can't create any references to my ViewController where the container view is in.

Comment: Your table view must have its delegate property set to the view controller (I assume it's view controller in your case) containing the `didSelect` method. That's the way the table view can call the method when the user taps the cell. You have two ways of doing it, either via Interface Builder, via the connection tab, or programmatically. I proposed you to do it programmatically to check if it solves your problem. Have you tried to do what I said? In the `viewdidLoad` of the controller where you wrote the `didSelect` method, add manually : `myTableView.delegate = self` What does it do?

Comment: It does not work. In my VC where I implemented the **didSelectRowAt** method is no reference to my table view. The table view is embedded in my container view (which is in the vc).. I tried several things but there is no way to connect it to the VC

Comment: So you have to set it in you segue that embeds the controller in you container. In you prepare for segue method you just do something like `(segue.destination as? MyControllerWithMyTableView)?.myTableView.delegate = self` Do you see what I mean?